# unable to load drools kie:ksession bean

Tags: java, spring, drools

I am using Drools 6.2.0 with spring integration.
    spring-context.xml file is below :

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:kie="http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

       <kie:kmodule id="poc-module">
            <kie:kbase name="kbase" packages="com.sample">
                <kie:ksession name="droolsSession">
                    <kie:consoleLogger />
                </kie:ksession>
            </kie:kbase>
        </kie:kmodule>
        <bean id="kiePostProcessor" class="org.kie.spring.KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor"/>    
        <bean id="ruleRunner" class="com.sample.RuleRunner"/>
    </beans>
```

Then I am getting below spring bean initialisation error when deploying the application.

```
[ERROR   ] Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet mvc-dispatcher  springexample
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
  Error creating bean with name 'droolsSession': 
  Cannot resolve reference to bean 'kbase' while setting bean property 'kBase';
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
  Error creating bean with name 'kbase':
  Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
  Unable to retrieve contents of directory 'C:\Documents and Settings'.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:618)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:602)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:521)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:325)
        at [internal classes]
```

It seems that drools kbase bean packages is trying to access root "/". Please suggest is any configuration I am missing in drools 6.2.0 Spring integration.

Answer (score -1):

Backslash character is the escape character in Java. To use it "as is", you have to double it: "\\".

If you pay attention, you will see that the path is not complete. It is probably trying to infer some default path.

Try to provide it explicitly.